# Send data by TCP connected to server by VPN

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, dns

I'm trying to send a packet by TCP to a server from VPN if I'm not connected to the local network, if I'm on the same local network I'm putting its IP if it's sent, but if I'm not and I'm passing the server's remote IP It gives an error.

**This code works for me if I'm in the same local network as the server:**

```
//Crear socket
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
//Definir Ip de destino y puerto
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.50");
int puerto = 8888;
//Apuntar a donde se enviara el mensaje
IPEndPoint destino = new IPEndPoint(ip, puerto);

try
{
    //Realizar conexion
    socket.Connect(destino);

    //Crear mensaje
    byte[] mensaje = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("shutdown");

    //Enviar mensaje
    var result = socket.Send(mensaje);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    socket.Close();
}
```

**But to do it from outside the local network connected to the VPN passing as address the ip obtained by DNS does not work for me:**

```
//Crear socket
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
//Definir Ip de destino y puerto
IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses("google.com")[0]; //it returns me for example ip 88.23.154.89
int puerto = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PUERTO_SERVIDOR"]);
//Apuntar a donde se enviara el mensaje
IPEndPoint destino = new IPEndPoint(ip, puerto);

try
{
    //Realizar conexion
    socket.Connect(destino);

    //Crear mensaje
    byte[] mensaje = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("shutdown");

    //Enviar mensaje
    var result = socket.Send(mensaje);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    socket.Close();
}
```

The error gives me in `socket.Connect(destino);`

> The connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond properly after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host was unable to respond 88.23.154.89:1025

Comment: three options I can think of: a) 88.23.154.89 is not the correct address - perhaps it is resolving to a generic public endpoint rather than the actual server (check the VPN-relative IP address of the name to check this), b) the IP is not configured correctly to route via the VPN, or c) there's a firewall issue and your TCP connection is being rejected along the way

Comment: But if I get the PING to the ip address

Comment: I'm assuming you've checked "a", and that the IP that you're pinging is the correct IP, but: ICMP (ping) isn't by itself enough - that doesn't say that the specific TCP port is available; for *that*, you could use `nmap` or `telnet` - see the answers here: https://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port (we just want to see whether it connects; you don't need to actually do anything interesting in `telnet` for example - just connect)

Comment: oh ok I solved that, but if I send a magic packet to turn on the PC the same thing happens to me from outside with VPN it doesn't work, would I have to enable a port for it? If so, how would the code look?           static async Task SendWakeOnLan(IPAddress localIpAddress, IPAddress multicastIpAddress, byte[] magicPacket)
        {
            using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(localIpAddress, 0)))
            {
                await client.SendAsync(magicPacket, magicPacket.Length, multicastIpAddress.ToString(), 9);
            }
        }